# Downloading JavaHelp library

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javahelp

I am developing a desktop application with java swing in NetBeans 
 I want to include an online help into the application by
 integrating the javahelp library into the system.

The meta data for the help set ha been created.

but looks like I am unable to find the link 
 to download binary distribution of the javahelp library.
 I used the following link https://javahelp.dev.java.net/#binary

but still not able to download.

can someone provide me with a more suitable link
 for the download.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `JavaHelp` project is no longer active. You can find a previous version of the binary [here](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/javahelp/javahelp2_0_05.zip)

Comment: Just for the information of anyone who happens upon this question, the Java.net site (referenced in this answer) is no longer operating.  This file can be found on the maven.org site: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.help/javahelp/2.0.05.